# WordPress docker container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am incredibly new to Docker, WordPress and Containers. I need to build a draft for a website and I want to use Docker containers as, for some reason, my VM does not work (cannot configure the web interface). I am following (copy-pasting, literally) this tutorial https://www.hostafrica.com/blog/wordpress/install-wordpress-docker-windows-linux/ on ubuntu.
When I get to create a yml file, I just copy pasted the info that is on the tutorial but I keep receiving error messages when I use the command 'docker-compose up -d'. The error is 'services must be a mapping'. I have googled and realised that this could be due to the lack of indentation in the text file, but I really don't have any skills at all to even understand how to change the indentation. I gave it a try and the error message changes slightly, so I almost sure this could be the cause of it? I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with this. I have copied the content of the yml file below

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
database:
image: mysql:5.7.37
volumes:
- database_data:/var/lib/mysql
restart: always
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootpassword
MYSQL_DATABASE: wp_db
MYSQL_USER: admin
MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
wordpress:
depends_on:
- database
image: wordpress:latest
ports:
- "8000:80"
restart: always
environment:
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp_db
volumes:
database_data: {}
```

Comment: What you've pasted into the question has no indentation at all, but YAML is very sensitive to lines being indented correctly.  Everything in this file except `version:`, `services:`, and the last `volumes:` needs to have at least one space at the start of the line.  Is your local file indented correctly?

Comment: Hi, no it isn't. That is my suspicion at least. Unfortunately, I am not a bioinformatician and I have no skills/experience with docker containers etc. I will try your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct docker compose for you...

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7.37
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp_db
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp_db
volumes:
  database_data:
```

- Ensured that the volumes section under the wordpress service has content. If you don't need to define a specific volume for the WordPress service, you can remove the volumes section entirely.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. This was very quick. Unfortunately I still get error messages. If I run the command with the file as it is (modified by you) I get ```services.wordpress.volumes must be a list``` and when I remove the volumes section all together at the end of the page, I get ```services.database_data must be a mapping``` At this stage I am not sure what to do/change. Any other suggestions?   Thanks Giulia

Comment: Don't remove the last volumes section. I corrected the file, check and apply again it will work now.

Comment: Ensured that the volumes section under the wordpress service has content. If you don't need to define a specific volume for the WordPress service, you can remove the volumes section entirely.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial link you provided is not a good one. It's really not that complicated when using Docker Desktop app and Docker Compose.

For starters, their `docker-compose.yml` examples are not even indented correctly, most decent IDE's will show this as invalid YAML/YML formatting.

YML's should be formatted with 2 space indents for each block (just like [@Ziyad Ansari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22118636/ziyad-ansari) answer). Anyway, not sure formatting is your problem, though might be.

Also MySQL is pretty old, use MariaDB instead, which is forked from MySQL image, and is a more up to date image of MySQL.

Anyway, to get WordPress running locally using Docker Compose is easy. First just install [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/).

Now don't over complicate database credentials, as these are only used locally, and makes it easier to remember for every local WordPress project you create. Makes is super easy when connecting to local database in your IDE.

Also, you don't need to define `volumes` to use in the database image block.

Here is the bare minimum you need in a `docker-compose.yml` file to fire up a local WordPress environment...

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:

  # here is our mariadb container
  # https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
  db:
    image: mariadb:11.0.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # here is our wordpress container
  # https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:

      # our docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

      # our docker wp config extra php defines
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /** disable wp core auto update */
        define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);
```

Just by running `docker-compose up`, or `docker-compose up -d` which is more handy to use as `-d` detaches the docker log and means you can run `docker-compose down` straight after in the same terminal window.

But be aware, as soon as you `docker-compose down`, this will destroy everything, when using the config above.

This is where Docker Compose gets awesome, you can map container volumes to your project directory so you can make database, themes, plugins, uploads etc persistent.

Mapping volume data so it is persistent, means everytime you `docker-compose down` your running project environment, next time your run `docker-compose up -d` on your local Docker WordPress project, all your environment data will be exactly as you left off.

Here is an persistent `docker-compose.yml` example showing you how to map volumes from your containers to make data persistent...

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:

  # here is our mariadb container
  # https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
  db:
    image: mariadb:11.0.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      # our persistent volume database mapping
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  # here is our wordpress container
  # https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      # our persistent volume sub directories mapping
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes
      - ./mu-plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/mu-plugins
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
    environment:

      # our docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

      # our docker wp config extra php defines
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /** disable wp core auto update */
        define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);
```

This is just the tip of the ice berg, see more extended examples of `docker-compose.yml` configuration files, enabling you to handle everything necessary when working locally with WordPress using Docker.

https://github.com/joshmoto/docker-wordpress-meetup-demo

The `README.md` is pretty rough, this was just to help Docker beginners from an online demo I did. If you got any questions let me know.

Happy Dockering!